# How to access the virtual property from the object of derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identity

I have inherited `IdentityUser` (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity) to my class `ClientUser`

```
public class ClientUser : IdentityUser
{
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
    public override string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a class which take client user as parameter.

```
private async Task<OperationStatus> DoOperation(ClientUser user)
{
}
```

but I am unable to access the property of `IdentityUser` from user.

[image: Properties that I get from object.]

Is there any way to access the virtual property with out overriding it.

Comment: What property are you trying to access?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I want to access all the property of IdentityUser class

Comment: Did you make it `public`?

Comment: I suspect your `identityUser` is not the [IdentityUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityuser?view=aspnetcore-1.1)... or `ClientUser` in screenshot is different from code you've posted... Make sure you really have [MCVE].

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Here I am using  IdentityUser from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`

Comment: Hi @AlexeiLevenkov I have updated my question can you check it once. :)

Comment: There is something wrong with whatever you are doing. Maybe you forgot to add NuGet, maybe it got restored wrong, maybe you are not using `IdentityUser` you think you are using,... I just tried the same setup and it works fine - cleaning and building may be the way...